# Is this a valid way of finding the an answer using the unit circle?

Tags: calculus

If I want to find what the value for $sin(-3 \pi) \over 4$ is, can I just find $sin(3 \pi) \over 4$ because it's easier (having a positive x) and then just multiply it by $-1$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sin \frac{-3\pi}{4}$? If so, then yes, because $\sin x$ is an odd function, meaning $\sin (-x) = -\sin x$. (Even if you didn’t mean that, it still applies, but it’s probably not what you meant.)

Comment: Yeah it wasn't what I meant I think I just got lucky by using that method. So I just learned about how $sin(x) = -sin(x)$ because it's an odd function but how come $cos(x) = cos(-x)$? That means that $cos(x)$ is an even function but isn't $sin$ and $cos$ sorta the same graph?

Comment: I’ll clarify on that right now.

Comment: They aren’t the same graph. They have the exact same shape but they’re $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians apart (in the case of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$). That’s like saying $y = 2x$ and $y = 2x+3$ are the same.

Comment: You are right that $\sin x$ is an odd function, and $\cos x$ is an even function.  And yes, the graph of one is a phase shift of the graph of the other.  The behavior of the graph around $0$ will show that one is even and one is odd.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine since sine is an odd function, it satisfies $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment, $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are even and odd functions, respectively. If you think about it in terms of the unit circle, things become clear.

For a straight line of length one drawn at angle $\theta$ from the origin of a unit circle to a point $B$ on the circumference, point $B$ will have the coordinates $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. This is obvious because

$$\cos \theta = \frac{adj}{hyp} = \frac{adj}{1} \implies adj = \cos\theta$$

$$\sin \theta = \frac{opp}{hyp} = \frac{opp}{1} \implies opp = \sin\theta$$

So, $\cos x$ corresponds with the $x$-axis and $\sin x$ corresponds with the $y$-axis. In quadrants $I$ and $II$, sine functions are positive as they deal with the upper portion of the $y$-axis. In quadrants $III$ and $IV$, sine functions are negative as they deal with the lower portion of the $y$-axis.

In quadrants $IV$ and $I$, cosine functions are positive since they deal with the right portion of the $x$-axis. In quadrants $II$ and $III$, cosine functions are positive since they deal with the left portion of the $x$-axis.

Combining this with the fact that $-\theta = 2\pi-\theta$, it becomes clear that $\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta$ and $\sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta$.

You can think of this visually. Imagine you draw an angle $\theta$ in the first quadrant and the exact same angle again but in the fourth quadrant ($-\theta$). You form two congruent right triangles. They **share** the same adjacent leg. Therefore, their cosine values are the same. However, their opposite legs extend the same amount but in opposite directions: upward for quadrant $I$ and downward for quadrant $IV$. Hence, their sine values are opposites.

This is also consistent with the fact that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ have the same graph but with phase shift $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Or, yet again, you could use well-known angle identities.

$$\sin (a\pm b) = \sin a\cos b\pm\cos a\sin b$$

$$\sin (0-\theta) = \sin 0\cos \theta-\cos 0\sin\theta = \color{blue}{-\sin\theta}$$

$$\cos(a\pm b) = \cos a\cos b\mp\sin a\sin b$$

$$\cos (0-\theta) = \cos 0\cos\theta+\sin 0\sin\theta = \color{blue}{\cos\theta}$$

Comment: Thanks! This helped

Comment: Glad to have helped. Doug M’s comment is also very useful. If you have any doubts, checking the graphs for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ should resolve them.